# Value in constructor doesn't change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm kinda new to writing OO JavaScript. I'm trying to do this one just for the sake of learning. My problem is, I defined a service with constructor, but it is ran only once.

Here's the code:

const app = angular.module('app', []);

```
class ViewportChecker {
    constructor() {
        this.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    }
}

app.directive('sectionModule', ($window) => {
    return {
        link(scope, el) {
            const service = new ViewportChecker,
                win = angular.element($window);

            win.on('scroll', () => {
                console.log(service.scrollTop);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I only get `0` in console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second you instantiate ViewportChecker the variable
window.pageYOfsset will probably be 0 (since you didn't scroll yet)

so when you later console.log (service.scrollTop) this variable will still be 0.

you assign this.scrollTop = 0 so to say, hence service.scrollTop will be always 0 in future.

what you can do is for example

```
constructor() {
    this.getScrollTop = function () { return window.pageYOffset; }
}
```

and

```
win.on('scroll', () => {
     console.log(service.getScrollTop());
 });
```